# Generalizations of Pedal Coordinates

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

I recently "stumbled upon" the article
[Pedal coordinates, Dark Kepler and other force problems](http://arxiv.org/abs/1704.00897) by Petr Blaschke from 2017;  further search about *Pedal Coordinates* didn't bring up any other relevant online resources; from the references on [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PedalCoordinates.html) I get the impression, that the topic hasn't been the subject and/or means of mathematical research for some decades.

> **Questions:**
>
> - where, except in the cited article by Petr Blaschke, have Pedal Coordinates played an important role in recent mathematical publications
> - have there been attempts to generalize Pedal Coordinates to higher dimensions and/or other numbers besides the reals like e.g. complex numbers

Comment: I was not sure about the tagging, so if someone could correct it, I'd appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** This article is from May 2018: [Notes on pedal and contrapedal curves of fronts in the Euclidean plane.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/mma.5056)